Getting on or off Greyhound Australia buses at night?
I've been thinking of using Greyhound Australia's buses to travel around Australia. The issue is that their buses can depart or arrive quite late at night, such as at midnight. When should I come to a bus stop to get on one of these late-night buses? And after getting off a bus, what should I do until morning arrives?
Asking as someone who plans to travel solo.

The Greyhound FAQs recommend you arrive 20 minutes prior to departure to ensure all your luggage is securely loaded. As to what to do until morning, that might well depend on where you get off and at what time. What route(s) do you have in mind? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73962/first-time-greyhound-traveller

@Traveller I'm planning on travelling up the east coast of Australia, making several stops, some of them lasting just one day (get off the bus one night, get on another bus the next night). I was wondering if this can be done without staying at a hotel or other accommodation.
